# Migrar mi base de datos de mysql a laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel, phpmyadmin

Soy nuevo con Laravel y estoy viendo si existe una forma de pasar la base de datos que tengo en mysql, a laravel para poder trabajar con ellas.

Yo he probado ya :

1. Modificar el .env.
2. Modificar el `config/database.php`.

Pero lo que encuentro es que puedes crear en Laravel una tabla y pasarla a mysql , pero lo que yo busco es lo contrario , o directamente , trabajar directamente entre mysql y laravel , sin necesidad de hacer ese punto intermedio del :

```
php artisan migrate
```

La mayoría de la información que encuentro es de crear tu la tabla y pasarla a mysql con el `php artisan migrate` eso si , en una base de datos vacía , pero yo la que tengo contiene datos y quiero trabajar sobre ella.

O solo me queda crear una clase en php por tabla en `database/migrations` , con los campos que tiene la base de datos e interactuar entre ellas.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el fin de "migrar" la base de datos?

Comment: Yo lo que busco es trabajar con la base de datos que tengo en mysql , desde Laravel.

Comment: Es simple si quieres conectarte as modificaciones en el archivo .env pero si quieres hacer el típico CRUD tienes que crear un modelo para cada tabla y manejarlo por el controlador estos videos me sirvieron bastante https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HANoD1NxhbY&list=PLvHC_bH_JxV1xCUEZuSyszWiBe5Cnq34Y

Comment: busque como loco aquí esta la solución ejecuten este codigo
<pre> QUEUE_DRIVER=database php artisan queue:work --daemon --quiet --sleep=1
</pre>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que confundes varios términos/tecnologías. No necesitas migrar una base de datos a *Laravel*. Básicamente porque *MySQL* es tu servicio de almacenamiento de datos y *Laravel* es un framework que puede utilizar cualquier servicio de almacenamiento de datos (entre otras cosas).

En tu pregunta deduzco que formulas varios problemas y que intentaré resolverlos en este comentario:

1. Usar una base de datos existente
2. y las Migraciones (de laravel)

**(1) Usar una base de datos**

*Laravel* te permite acceder a datos de varias maneras.

- Directamente sin usar *Laravel* instanciando un *PDO*, o cualquier otro conector (esto no es aconsejable).
- Utilizando *DB*
- Utilizando *Eloquent*

Si quieres utilizar *DB* o *Eloquent* solo tienes que configurar el fichero *"config/database.php"* con los datos.

Con **DB** es tan sencillo como hacer algo tal que ([más info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database))

```
$results = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

**Eloquent** es un *ORM* ([más info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)) que te permite interactuar con la base de datos mediante modelos (clases). Estos modelos están asociados a una tabla en tu base de datos. De tal modo que podría hacer algo tal que

```
$all_users_of_my_database = App\Users::all();
```

O

```
App\Users::where('email', 'esto@es.test')->first()
```

**(2) Migraciones de Laravel**

Las migraciones en *Laravel* se podrían asemejar a tener un sistema de control de versiones, sobre tu base de datos. Por ejemplo, cuando quieres crear una tabla nueva, en vez de hacerlo directamente desde *MySQL*, lo que generarías es una migración para tal finalidad. También se utilizan las migraciones para alterar los campos de las tablas y no tenerlo que hacer directamente en *MySQL*: En uno o varios campos, añadir, eliminar, cambiar el tipo, etc.

Ejemplo:

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_users --create=users --table=users
Created Migration: 2016_11_18_164149_create_table_users
```

Donde tú luego añadirías las columnas nombre, apellidos y correo electrónico.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->string('email');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

Después de esto, únicamente con ejecutar la migración Laravel, ya te crearía la tabla con las columnas descritas.

**Resumiendo**

Cuando tu base de datos ya existe (porque la implementaste en su día) no es necesario que crees las migraciones para lo que ya existe, únicamente para las nuevas modificaciones (opcionalmente). Si no quieres, puedes ir haciendo tu aplicación con *Laravel* por una parte y trabajar con la manipulación de tu base de datos directamente con *MySQL*.

**Editado 2**: Por favor, antes de realizar modificaciones consultad al autor de la respuesta. En general no me parece mal los cambios a excepción del primero, que no es un "O" sino un "Y". Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda , ahora mismo estoy leyendo un libro sobre laravel y esto me ha sido de una buena guía.

Comment: @CodeNoob espero que hayas podido avanzar :)

Comment: Si , he avanzado muchísimo desde esta pregunta , se agradece mucho la ayuda que brinda un sitio como este a la gente con dudas , que nos podamos ayudar con nuestros comentarios.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es poder utilizar Eloquent o el Query builder y no tener que generar los modelos manualmente, puedes utilizar algunos paquetes que existen:

https://github.com/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator

https://medium.com/@CristianLLanos/eloquent-models-from-my-database-5d74c632e03c#.vqafn9k39

Esto asumiendo que tengas más de 10 o 20 tablas y que la generación de sus relaciones sea compleja, de lo contrario yo crearía los modelos manualmente, no es algo complicado y tampoco tarda mucho tiempo.

Comment: Gracias también por la ayuda.

Comment: Muy útil ese Laravel Model Generator pero se actualizó a [Reliese Laravel](https://github.com/reliese/laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Es simple si quieres conectarte as modificaciones en el archivo .env pero si quieres hacer el típico CRUD tienes que crear un modelo para cada tabla y manejarlo por el controlador estos videos me sirvieron bastante 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HANoD1NxhbY&list=PLvHC_bH_JxV1xCUEZuSyszWiBe5Cnq34Y

Comment: agrega la información más reelevante de los enlaces en tu respuesta. Revisa [answer], saludos.